# How to modify two databes tables in one form in Yii

Tags: php, database, forms, yii

I have created one form to eddit one table(hotel_rooms) in my database from my website page, it works perdectcly.
But I need to include some fields,not all the table, from another table (hotel_rooms_checked)in the edditing web page of the privious table (hotel_rooms)
how can I do it please ? where `hotel_rooms.Id = hotel_rooms_checked.Id`
here is the code for the form

```
    <?php
    /* @var $this HotelRoomsController */
    /* @var $model HotelRooms */
    /* @var $form CActiveForm */
    ?>

    <div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'hotel-rooms-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Id'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Id',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'Id'); ?>
        </div>

.......
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div><!-- form -->
```

and this is the controller code

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['HotelRooms']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['HotelRooms'];
            if($model->save())
        // $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);

                $this->redirect(array('hotels/index','id'=>$model->Id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

the view code is

```
<?php
/* @var $this HotelRoomsController */
/* @var $model HotelRooms */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Hotel Rooms'=>array('index'),
    $model->Id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List HotelRooms', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create HotelRooms', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Update HotelRooms', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->Id)),
    array('label'=>'Delete HotelRooms', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->Id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('label'=>'Manage HotelRooms', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>View Room : <?php echo $model->Id; ?></h1>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'data'=>$model2,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'Id',
        'HotelName',
        'HotelRoomsType',
        ....
    ),
)); ?>
```

the structure oh the tables

```
Hotel_Rooms
Id
HotelName
HotelRoomsType
.....

Hotel_Rooms_Checked
Id
DateCheckedIn
DateCheckedOut
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the question seems to be not clear enough. I would try to guess what you want though.

For the `view`, just add the fields for the other `model` (I suppose you have created a model for `hotel_rooms_checked`)

```
<?php
    /* @var $this PropUnitController */
    /* @var $model HotelRooms */
    /* @var $model2 HotelRoomsChecked */
    /* @var $form CActiveForm */
    ?>

    <div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'hotel-rooms-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($model, $model2)); ?>

        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Id'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Id',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'Id'); ?>
        </div>

        <!--for example, let's say we have an attribute `status` for HotelRoomsChecked-->
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model2,'status'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model2,'status',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model2,'status'); ?>
        </div>

.......
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div><!-- form -->
```

And now for the controller, you could perform the validation for both models before actually saving.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $model2 = HotelRoomsChecked::model()->findByPk($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['HotelRooms']) && isset($_POST['HotelRoomsChecked']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['HotelRooms'];
            $model2->attributes = $_POST['HotelRoomsChecked'];
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = $valid && $model2->validate();

            if($valid) {
        // $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
                $model->save();
                $model2->save();
                $this->redirect(array('hotels/index','id'=>$model->Id));
            }
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'model2' => $model2,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: thanls for the replay
I tried it but I have this error : Undefined variable: model2

Comment: always the same error even after adding  'model2' => $model2,

Comment: well, _form is the view file. Anyway, could you please try to add a few lines of codes after "$model2 = HotelRoomsChecked::model()->findByPk($id);" in the controller: if ($model2 == null) echo "missing"; else echo "fine"; to see if $model2 is instantiated properly?

Comment: oh i just found that you used "CDetailView" in the view file. "CDetailView" is for displaying details for ONE single model. That may be why you got the errors. Try to use another CDetailView for $model2.

Comment: I didi it but it still shows that the Undefined variable: model2 in the _form code ??

Comment: Probably you forgot to pass the variable into _form from the view. The controller passed $model2 to the view, and you have to pass $model2 AGAIN to the _form.

Comment: finally I found the error where does it come from I forgot to add model2 in the update and creat file like this  echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model,'model2' => $model2)); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass both models from the controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // assuming second model has same ID. Modify $id accordingly
    $model2=HotelRoomsChecked::model()->findByPk($id);

    if(isset($_POST['HotelRooms']) && isset($_POST['HotelRoomsChecked'])) //!
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['HotelRooms'];
        $model2->attributes=$_POST['HotelRoomsChecked']; //!

        if($model->save() && $model2->save()) //!
            $this->redirect(array('hotels/index','id'=>$model->Id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'model2'=>$model2, //!
    ));
}
```

And simply use the second model in your form the same way that you have posted in your question.

Comment: thanks for the replay I tried it but I have this error : Undefined variable: model2

Comment: the error is in _form code and I alredy added   /* @var $model2 HotelRoomsChecked */ in the first line of the _form code

Comment: that's what Im getting
<pre>
object(HotelRoomsChecked)[89]
  private '_md' (CActiveRecord) => 
    object(CActiveRecordMetaData)[67]
      public 'tableSchema' => 
        object(CMysqlTableSchema)[68]
          public 'schemaName' => null
          public 'name' => string 'hotek_rooms_checked' (length=12)
          public 'rawName' => string '`hotek_rooms_checked`' (length=14)
          public 'primaryKey' => string 'Id' (length=2)
          public 'sequenceName' => null
          public 'foreignKeys' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...<code>